# Javascript - Adding Video Element features to embedded Youtube content

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

let me start with what I already have:
HTML5:

```
<video id= "video" preload=auto autoplay controls>
<source src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

JS:

```
<script>
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", start);
var track;
var data;
var currentX, currentY;
function start(){
    data = video.getBoundingClientRect();
    track = video.addTextTrack("captions", "English", "en");
    video.addEventListener("mousemove", movement);         

}
function movement(e){
    currentX = e.clientX, currentY = e.clientY;

}
</script>
```

So as you can see, I have basic HTML5 video element, to which I add events and manipluate later on in various ways. One of the things I do with these events is adding dynamic captions(addTextTrack) to my HTML5 video via ajax call to a Node server. It all works fine, but here is the actual problem:

I want to be able to do all of these things with the youtube API:

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QtXby3twMmI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but can't do many of the things listed above because youtube provides an Iframe to work with.

Now last thing, I'd appreciate solutions without using jQuery or big libraries because at the end, I suggest an API myself to clients, and I do not want to force big libraries on them. Thank you.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Comment: Indeed, there are some features over there but I didn't find a way to add listeners such as getting cords information by mouse movement over the element, or how to add tracks(addTextTrack)...

Comment: sorry don't know of any other ways

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option that youtube provides, which are available [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#enablejsapi) or if those are to limiting you can
download the video with [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) and host it on your server. Then you can use it like an other html5 video.

Warning: Using youtube-dl may not be legal (it violates Google's TOS). Consult a lawyer first.

Comment: What are you suggesting exactly, that I'll download every youtube video they need via some sort of registration, and  then stream it to my clients through a video element? I can't do it at the moment. too many resources are at stake.

Comment: @RunningFromShia I can't think of another way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awesome **[Plyr](https://github.com/Selz/plyr)** package and install it via: *npm*, *bower*, *Ember* or *use* a *CDN*

- It's semantic ( `<video>` tag )
- Responsive
- For Youtube and Vimeo
- Written in "vanilla" JavaScript ( No libraries dependencies )

and **the total weight is less than 60 Kb** totally acceptable.

By now i think this is the best choice :) hope help you.

Comment: From what I see, they let you add the event listeners I mentioned above only to non-youtube videos. Their youtube API is still just an Iframe they manipulate and I don't think you can add to that Iframe event listeners like captions and mousemove, if you think it's possible maybe demonstrate?

Comment: I was trying yesterday man, but cannot figure out how to do it, srr

Comment: Yes, that's probably because Iframes have restrictions that don't let you do that...